# how to fetch user phone number using loginViewFetchedUserInfo?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

I am using FBLoginView to login authentication and get user info in my iOS Application.

I got all the information of FB user using FBLoginView and its below delegate method

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
}
Response is :-
bio = "some bio";
email = "email address";
"first_name" = My first name;
gender = male;
id = my id;
"last_name" = my last name;
link = "face book url link";
locale = "en_US";
name = "my full name";
timezone = "5.5";
"updated_time" = "2014-05-29T12:59:48+0000";
verified = 1;
```

now problem is that I am not getting the user's phone number only.

any help ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No its not possible to get phone number because below link says that there is no phone number permission.

Click [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user).

Comment: but how to pass parameter here?

Comment: FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]]; and you can get its delegate method as below. and if you still not understand then ask the question and give me link I will provide the code because here only 480 characters to fill                     -(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
}

Comment: No i mean in the following code
` [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                 parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              NSLog(@"\n\nResults: %@",result);
                          }];`

Comment: Oh sorry I have implemented above code for FB authentication. and I got enough detail about user who logged in so no need to implement FBRequestConnection. so again sorry for that

Comment: Please let me know how do i get birthday, profie picture via FBRequestConnection

Answer (score 2):

I think because of FBLoginView, and new Facebook SDK of iOS you're facing this problem.

Comment: Yes I think so thanks for answer but still any help will appreciate

Comment: brother its not possible to get phone number via facebook API.